# jLinq - Fazer query dinamica pegando valores do 'Select'

Tags: jquery, array, linq

Estou usando [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq/demo) para buscar em um `Array` de `Objetos`
Eu gostaria que essa busca fosse dinamica, pegando os valores dos `Selects`

meu exemplo:

```
<select id="firt"><option>Select 1</option></select>
<select id="last"><option>Select 2</option></select>
<select id="phone"><option>Select 3</option></select>

myNewArray = jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )
             .equals( "first", $( "#first" ).find( "option:selected" )  
             .equals( "last",  $( "#last" ).find( "option:selected" )
             .equals( "phone", $( "#phone" ).find( "option:selected" )
             .group( "state" );
```

mas eu quero algo assim:

```
myNewArray = jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )
             //for each selected option
             .group( "state" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode montar a query como se fosse texto e depois executar através da função `eval()`. Exemplo:

```js
function montaQuery() {
  var query = 'jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )';
  
  $('select').each(function(index) {
    query += '.equals( "' + this.id + '", "' + this.value + '")';
  });
  
  query += '.group( "state" );'
  
  $('#query').html(query);
  
  //myNewArray = eval(query);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first"><option>Select 1</option></select>
<select id="last"><option>Select 2</option></select>
<select id="phone"><option>Select 3</option></select>

<br/>
<input type="button" value="Prepara a query!" onclick="montaQuery()"/>

<p id="query"></p>
```

Uma observação, o **ID** do seu primeiro select está escrito errado. Estava `firt`, arrumei pra `first`.

Para executar a query é só fazer o comando:

```
myNewArray = eval(query);
```

Comment: funcionou perfeito! muito obrigado!!